# Cumulative sum with conditional subtraction using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, cumulative-sum

I am trying to calculate a conditional cumulative sum using the **dplyr** package in R. I am building a savings calculator with negative shocks. So I want a variable that has cumulative savings, minus the shocks. This seems like it should be fairly straightforward using the lag function, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Here is an example:

```
event <- c(0,0,0,1,0) 
save <- rep(.5,5)
## add up the savings from each prior row, then when event is one subtract 1
output_want <- c(.5,1,1.5,1,1.5) 
df <- tibble(event,save,output_want) %>% 
  mutate(totsave = if_else(row_number() ==1, save, 0)) %>% 
  mutate(totsave = if_else(row_number() !=1, save+lag(totsave)-event, save))
```

Ideally I would like to make the negative savings shock be a fraction of the accumulated savings, but thought I'd start with a simpler case.

Answer (score 2):

If at each time step you want to add the savings from the `save` vector but subtract the shock from `event`, then you can compute the desired result by taking the cumulative sum of `save-event`:

```
cumsum(save-event)
# [1] 0.5 1.0 1.5 1.0 1.5
```

Comment: Thank you. That works great. I can also subtract a fraction of the cumulative sum like so 
`cumsum(save-event*0.5*cumsum(save))`
Do you know why the lag function i was originally working with doesn't work?

Comment: @williamlief Your version with `lag` didn't every cumulatively sum anything, so I don't see how it could have added up the savings from one period to the next.